# Playing around with mongodb $expr $gt and $and together doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

I am playing around with mongodb but facing trouble with using $expr $gt and $and operator.

created playground for better understanding..

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W48t1KBfspo)

What I want here if history collection's date is greater than main collection date and and check history's user_id not in with my input id. then it will not display any data otherwise display all data how it possible please guide

Comment: Can you rephrase your requirements without double negatives so that they are easier to follow?

Comment: I want to display only those which are lesser than main collection's date which will compare from history's date and whose entered user_id not in history's collection

Comment: So you want main date < history date, but your aggregation pipeline requires main date > history date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "history",
      localField: "history_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "History"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$History"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $in: [
              "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5763",
              "$History.user_id"
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $gt: [
              "$date",
              "$History.date"
            ]
          },
          else: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

we can use `$cond` to match our requirements

this will return the following

1- if the specified userId exists in the user_id array, then it will get all the documents which have date > history date

2- if the specified userId does not exist in the user_id array, it will return all the documents

check this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YLlpAQxx7zt)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212625/discussion-on-answer-by-mohammed-yousry-playing-around-with-mongodb-expr-gt-an).